# Tool for solving Lagrange (System of linear equations)

Tags: systems-of-equations, lagrange-multiplier, finance

I'm searching for a tool that helps me solving systems of linear equations in the context of Lagrange functions (domain of financial markets and optimal consumption bundles). The excellent Wolframalpha is not sufficient enough, as I want to solve equations like this for $x$ and $\lambda$:

$$ I: \frac{x^{\gamma-1}}{\gamma} - \lambda p = 0 $$
$$ II: -p(x-w) = 0 $$

Comment: *Mathematica* ($x=w$ and $\lambda = \frac{w^{\gamma - 1}}{p \gamma}$)  Ummm... and what does $\stackrel{!}{=}$ mean in your context?

Comment: What a pity: My Windows version is not supported by Mathematica. The =! is not important in that context, as the problem is solving systems of linear equations. So they are equal to = here.

Comment: I urge you, then, to fix your "equations" as they are confusing.